# ImageResizer - Resize all Images within a Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing, imageresizer

I am trying to re-size every image within a folder. I was trying to find a way to specify the folder and I could re-size every image within it, possibly using a plugin (something like FolderResizeSyntax, although I am not 100% sure exactly how this works yet). Another approach would be to loop through my SQL server table, grab the file path, use that file path to open the file on my computer, then re-size it. The latter does not seem very efficient. Current re-size code is posted below. Help on how to re-size all images within a folder would be appreciated.

```
Dictionary<string, string> versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//Define the versions to generate
versions.Add("_Original", ""); //Original Image
versions.Add("_1000", "width=1000&height=1000&crop=auto"); //Fit to 1000x1000 area
versions.Add("_500", "width=500&height=500&crop=auto"); //Fit to 500x500 area
versions.Add("_250", "width=250&height=250&crop=auto"); //Fit to 250x250 area

//Loop through each uploaded file
foreach (string fileKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys)
{
    //Generate each version
    foreach (string suffix in versions.Keys)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];
        if (file.ContentLength <= 0) continue; //Skip unused file controls.

        //Create directory/path based on file type (ex. _Raw, _1000, etc.)
        string uploadFolder = MapPath("~/myImages/" + suffix);

        //Get the physical path for the uploads folder and make sure it exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);

        string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, file.FileName + suffix);

        //Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
        fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file, fileName, new Instructions(versions[suffix]), false, true)).FinalPath;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning on using the different file sizes in a website? The beauty of ImageResizer is that it'll create different image sizes on the fly and then cache them so that the commonly used ones are fast. ex> http://somewebsite/Content/myimage?width=100 that way you wouldn't need to manually resize each file. You keep the large images and ImageResizer makes any size image that is requested on the fly.

Comment: If this is a one time thing, I'd recommend using a program built for this something like http://lifehacker.com/5147153/bulk-image-resizer-is-light-and-quick-on-photo-processing

Comment: I don't know how many times I may use this. I have a folder with images and I may want to resize all of them to 300x300 and put them  in a new folder or 250x200 and put those in a different new folder for future use.

Comment: You'll either want to use/install ImageResizer on your website and then keep the original files which can be re-sized on the fly to any size that is needed, or you'll want to use a program similar to http://lifehacker.com/5147153/bulk-image-resizer-is-light-and-quick-on-photo-processing which will do this conversion and then you don't need resizer.  The following link is to a website that helped me realize the correct way to use ImageResizer http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
Dictionary<string, string> versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//Define the versions to generate
versions.Add("_Raw", ""); //Original Image
versions.Add("_1000x1000", "width=1000&height=1000&crop=auto"); //Fit to 1000x1000 area
versions.Add("_500x500", "width=500&height=500&crop=auto"); //Fit to 500x500 area

string[] path2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\myPictures\TestImages");
//Generate each version
foreach (string dirFile in path2)
{
    foreach (string suffix in versions.Keys)
    {
        //Create directory/path based on file type (ex. _Raw, _1000, etc.)
        string uploadFolder = MapPath("~/TestImages/" + suffix.Replace("_", ""));

        //Get the physical path for the uploads folder and make sure it exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);

        ////Generate a filename.
        string filePath = Path.GetFileName(dirFile);
        string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, filePath + suffix);

        //Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
        fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(dirFile, fileName, new Instructions(versions[suffix]), false, true)).FinalPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also probably check out this page on ImageResizer's website. It's about applying a watermark to all images in a folder over a certain size, but the per-folder application is the same, and it'd probably require less code than the above answer.

http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/watermark-by-folder-or-size